# Using php to send push notifications to Mozilla

Tags: php, push-notification

I am working on a project that allows users to subscribe for notifications. When user subscribes for this service on Mozilla I save his credentials returned by Mozilla server. For example:

```
Endpoint: https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABls-VTdPbyYof9HsUS0UMzNKZKp4EZp7-E1Ie20jQr1hs8F_ldvL-8PN0PHFdXBF2WR2bU9ugjjo9Hai_mitDl61WGBMZxv4VX8rFtkeLLO6o5NefMBmYw2_rzx-8Zm8uYEhnbadlm_owVBIWKNHKBxZN-r7IwR23Muj5MRzDgu6XR5QU 
Auth: UZxEdySeaeA-gbGY0sAJSQ
P256dh: BB6CcBQo7GxNaMp03T3deANrB2R_5kNPB6XOZlLBodJKnjrN09iS6l5xNgTxi2VstkX-oMxeSTkCqwoGoEXZ3e8
```

My question is:
How can I send request via php cURL to Mozilla server so the user to get the notification?
these are my browser app credentials:

```
$publicVapidKey = 'BOzdJ4aWDSZPeDcUZmapdwN5wcrZkOzzS238W0djUC7LJQKV1dK35WPFHDpbIGWm1J4fB-ppeWRQyT2IfC_7n-s';
$privateVapidKey = 'oyMYznamu0--gwnAFS6zqMij8pErOg2FVuXvYh77UI4';
```

My php function:

```
function sendPushNotification($endpoint, $auth, $p256dh, $publicVapidKey, $privateVapidKey, $payload) {
$subscription = array(
    'endpoint' => $endpoint,
    'keys' => array(
        'auth' => $auth,
        'p256dh' => $p256dh,
    ),
);

$vapidHeader = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . base64_encode($privateVapidKey),
    'Crypto-Key: p256ecdsa=' . $publicVapidKey,
);

$payload = json_encode($payload);

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array_merge(
        array('Content-Type: application/json'),
        $vapidHeader
    ),
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // You may want to change this in a production environment
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}
```

// Example usage:

```
$endpoint = 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABls-VTdPbyYof9HsUS0UMzNKZKp4EZp7-E1Ie20jQr1hs8F_ldvL-8PN0PHFdXBF2WR2bU9ugjjo9Hai_mitDl61WGBMZxv4VX8rFtkeLLO6o5NefMBmYw2_rzx-8Zm8uYEhnbadlm_owVBIWKNHKBxZN-r7IwR23Muj5MRzDgu6XR5QU';
$auth = 'UZxEdySeaeA-gbGY0sAJSQ';
$p256dh = 'BB6CcBQo7GxNaMp03T3deANrB2R_5kNPB6XOZlLBodJKnjrN09iS6l5xNgTxi2VstkX-oMxeSTkCqwoGoEXZ3e8';
$publicVapidKey = 'BOzdJ4aWDSZPeDcUZmapdwN5wcrZkOzzS238W0djUC7LJQKV1dK35WPFHDpbIGWm1J4fB-ppeWRQyT2IfC_7n-s';
$privateVapidKey = 'oyMYznamu0--gwnAFS6zqMij8pErOg2FVuXvYh77UI4';
$payload = array(
'title' => 'New Notification',
'body' => 'This is a test push notification.',
);

$response = sendPushNotification($endpoint, $auth, $p256dh, $publicVapidKey, $privateVapidKey, $payload);
```

And the response is:

```
Response: {"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"InvalidToken","more_info":"http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"}
```

What is wrong here guys.. Please help, it's been a week since I can't make it work and could not find examples on the net that are not using Firebase as mediator..
Thanks !